# Jave SQL executeQuery throws up error for valid sql statement

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using java java.sql.* for querying from SQLite DB. I found a starnge issue where I write a sqlString as:

```
SELECT n.Name as Name, 
       c.Value as Value0, 
       d.Value as Value1 
FROM  (Table1 c inner join Table2 n on c.NameID = n.ID),
      Table3 d 
WHERE c.RunID = 1 
      and d.RunID = 2 
      and c.NameID = d.NameID
```

The statement `stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery)` throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: n.Name
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:89).............
```

`Name` is already part of the Table2 table. The same statement is working fine from SQLite command prompt. But when I remove the open brackets and try to execute from java, there is no problem. Any idea why this happens so?

Comment: What application are you using to execute the SQL "directly"?  Is there any chance that the user application is doing some translation of the input before sending it to the DB server proper?  I'd be surprised if the database responded differently to the exact same input depending on which system sent it.

Comment: I am access sqlite db directly from java code as I described earlier. And there is only select statment in the java code. No insertion/update.

Comment: I guess you are using the sqlite command shell. Are you sure, you are using the same version? The sqlite library is usually compiled into the command shell and so it is not guaranteed, that it is the same as you use with your java program. For example, with version 3.6.6 I see the same error message as you see in Java and with SQLite version 3.7.13, I see no error message. So, this behaviour has changed in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, use sub resultset

```
SELECT rs1.Name AS NAME, 
       rs1.Value0 AS Value0, 
       d.Value AS Value1 
FROM  (SELECT n.Name AS NAME, 
       c.Value AS Value0, 
       d.Value AS Value1 
       FROM Table1 c INNER JOIN Table2 n ON c.NameID = n.ID) rs1,
      Table3 d 
WHERE c.RunID = 1 
      AND d.RunID = 2 
      AND c.NameID = d.NameID
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables used in inner queries could not be referred outside. For example, you have used the variable n in inner sql. But you are referring it outside. The variable n is out of it's scope there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friends Thanks for your fast responses. I am able to solve this problem. I am sharing this so if any1 else get this problem can do this:

```
SELECT ABC.Name as Name, ABC.Value as Value0, d.Value as Value1
  FROM
  (select n.Name as Name, c.Value as Value0 from Table1 c
   inner join Table2 n on c.NameID = n.ID) AS ABC,
Table3 d ......;
```

Regards,Tor

Comment: This is exactly Rahul's answer.. Kindly accept his answer (so that anyone else having the same problem can see how to solve this).

Comment: I didnt seen that :) . so posted my answer! Thanks, Tor